# how to write validation rule for child object on basis of parent object by lookup relationship?

Tags: validation-rule

I have two objects, one is event and other is attendee. Attendee has to select event in the form of lookup relationship. Event has two types of ticket, general and vip. Attendee won't select vip category when the event VIP ticket price is equal to zero.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! It sounds like you know what you want the validation rule to do. What have you tried so far? This site isn't really about doing your work for you, but rather helping you overcome specific problems to become a better programmer/admin. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and if you're new to Salesforce or validation rules in general, drop by trailhead.salesforce.com to get a handle on the basics.